# How to uninstall a program whose content already deleted?

Tags: 12.04, networking, gnome-terminal, delete

i'm new to Ubuntu Really need help in this problem 
Now i installed old version of a program that used a port for its processes , i deleted the folder of the program by `right click .. remove` and didn't know that it has any files in other place !! and didn't know that may be a process using port

i installed new version of the program and every time i ran the program , old version folder created and `empty` !!

Now i want to delete old version folder completely in right way 
i searched for `PID` of the old version but it gave nothing !! sure because i deleted the folder of the program , HOW can i solve this

Comment: What is "the program"?

Comment: storm is an open source

Comment: How did you install the program? What instructions did you use? how is one to help you if you do not betray details?

Comment: ok i installed it using terminal by getting there files using( wget url_of_program_release ) then following specific commands in terminal i can't write it all of them now

Answer (score 0):

first run `sudo apt-get autoremove` in case there are some non used packages left

then `sudo rmdir /path/to/folder` inorder to ReMove the dir of the folder.

Comment: i  used the above command but got unable to locate package , and couldn't find any package by regex